# yii2 get sum and related model data together

Tags: activerecord, group-by, yii2, sum

Below is my query. I want the sum of the hours. But when I write select, it does not return the data of the related model.

```
$query = JobPositions::find()
                ->select(['sum(assign_applicant.hours) as hours'])
                ->joinWith(['assign','position','shift'])
                ->groupBy(['position_id','shift_id']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);
```

The below line return the data when I remove the select line from the above query.

```
$model->position->name
```

what should be the solution to this when I want both ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add explictally the columns you need eg:

```
  $query = JobPositions::find()
                ->select(['sum(assign_applicant.hours) as hours', 'name'])
                ->joinWith(['assign','position','shift'])
                ->groupBy(['position_id','shift_id']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);
```

or

```
  $query = JobPositions::find()
                ->select('*, sum(assign_applicant.hours) as hours')
                ->joinWith(['assign','position','shift'])
                ->groupBy(['position_id','shift_id']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
```

Comment: Thanks. Picked the first option